# Everybody knows I only see my job as a paycheck and this is causing harm

Tags: motivation

Ive have had a position for 4 years (Europe, full-time, permanent contract, 30k+ employees) and I myself know that my time is due, I cant grow more, I learnt what I wanted to learn, the new colleagues does not interest me. In these crazy times though I value the job security, possibility to work remotely and that the job is stress free.

My first 3 years I was interacting with everyone, setting up events, picking up extra tasks, having learning circles etc. This is how the "old-timers" used to know me, however, I simply realised that doing minimum is better, and that is what I have been doing the whole year. To clarify, I am still performing and fulfilling my responsibilities.

Every lead in our team (1 manager, 5 leads, 50 colleagues) seem to know this and as my currect assignment is ending I have been asked by the manager to have talks with the leads to see if I can join them.

Ive had 2 talks where there was not a click but I was also told that I did not seem motivated working with what they are doing, which is true, my main motivation is my paycheck. I also know that my manager asked a lead to take me, but said he did not want to.

Recently I had a talk with my manager where he expressed his concerns about my future in the team and my motivation. I openly said that indeed I was demotivated, the team has changed to the worse, the tasks are not that interesting anymore and that I am only doing things that I was not hired to do. I do not know if I should have been this transparent.

My manager on the other hand is not a transparent person and started saying that it would be a shame if I left, but he also mentioned that he is willing to "help me leave" and that looking for other departments is always an option. I dont know what his help involves, writing a reference letter, severance pay (never heard of in our department) etc. **My take from this is that he really wants me to leave, because he does not know what do with me.** He also asked if I had thought about my future and I said "I do not have any plans on leaving this team". A lie, but he believes in it.

Now I am in a situation where I need to have talks with my manager how to get me back to being a overachiver, while the only thing I want is my paycheck. He is puttng more preassure that I need to get an assignment, but this is not my responsibility. The atmosphere between the colleagues is also starting to get really awkward. I do not interact with the colleagues on a personal level so not much of a loss there.

How should I continue this? Currently it feels like I'm faking it, trying to be interested with fear of loosing my paycheck. Shall I simply say that it is his responsibility to assign tasks and I will do whatever I'm told to do? If he wants me to leave, he should pay me severance pay (I am open to this).

Would also be interested to hear of the negative consequences are of what I am doing right now. No career growth, no learning and reputational damage is what I can think of.

Comment: Voting to close since the OP is asking us to consider if he should leave a job. Best advice I can give is don't take criticism from people you wouldn't take advice from.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to continue doing the minimum but somehow make people have a higher opinion of you? Do you want to become a full part of the team again, even if it means working harder? Do you want to leave/transfer but feel you are unable to (for whatever reason, financial, practical, psychological...)? Are you happy to continue working this way, but worry you're going to get fired?

Answer (score 2):

I would say one thing, it sounds like you have a case of burnout due to remote work while COVID running around.

You are not the only one that afflicted with this, actually it has been a trend lately in development world.

Being stuck at home, juggling work/life balance without having an outlet to go to the office for more structured interactions

**I would suggest, when you talk to your manager, ask for help in that department.**

Comment: I did not think it would be relevant, but I have actually been off 3 months for burnout during Covid. These months off did help me get my personal life together, but going back to work it was also the starting point of my mentality to do minimum.

Comment: @MLEN its not easy, but you can get back

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not really doing the bare minimum right now although you do think that. I say that because if you did, you wouldn't be in a situation, where management cannot find a role for you to fill. It seems that your colleagues started seeing you as an underperformer. I am not saying this is bad  or anything, all people have their ups and downs. Just that the way how you and your colleagues perceive your performance seems to be different.

It might help your situation to clearly define expectations for your role at the company with your manager. Your manager probably won't be content with you doing only what you are told to. But until you clarify the expectations, there is no sure way to tell. After you get this information, you will be able to decide whether or not you are able to fulfill the expectations. Together with what you said about your job (having learnt everything you wanted there, no more growth, etc.), you can make an informed decision about your future.

This will require some proactivity from you, which will be hard, since you mention burnout, but delaying might bring you even more tension due to the uncertainty of your situation. Thus, making your future moves clear should be a priority for you.

Keep in mind, that the damage might be done already and there is a possibility that you cannot salvage this situation and retain your position. Therefore it would be useful to start looking for other employment options.

Answers to your questions:
No one here or anywhere else can really tell you how you should continue. People around you can only give advice about what actions might help you to make a decision.

Other than what you said and keeping in mind that you mentioned burnout, negative consequences can be long term health problems and loss of personal or work connections.